# What is the difference between Babel options brazil and brazilian?

Tags: babel

The Babel documentation lists both options but I did not find where it describes the difference.  I found one Brazilian website saying "Use a opção brazil para escrever no nosso português" but it never mentioned the other option.

Comment: There is no difference, they are synonyms, one in Portuguese and the other in English.

Comment: @gernot You are probably right about the motivation.  But in fact "Brazil" and "Brazilian" are both English.  In Brazilian Portuguese they are Brasil and brasileiro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading the [package documentation of babel-portuges](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel-portuges):

> Now we have to decide whether this language definition file was loaded for Portuguese or Brasilian use. This can be done by checking the contents of `\CurrentOption`. When it doesn't contain either `portuges` or `portuguese` we make `\bbl@tempb` empty.

I would say that `brazil` and `brazilian` are equivalent.